# What is the most popular resolution category by state?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have the top cathegory value for each state

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(tweet_category) AS category_count, tweet_category, tweet_state
FROM [New_years_resolutions_2020]
GROUP BY tweet_state, tweet_category
ORDER BY tweet_state, category_count DESC;
```

| catehgory_count | tweet_cathegory | tweet_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Personal Growth | AK |
| 4 | Family/Friends | AK |
| 3 | Health/Fitness | AK |
| 2 | Humor | AK |
| 15 | Health/Fitness | AL |
| 8 | Family/Friends | AL |
| 6 | Personal Growth | AL |
| 9 | Humor | AL |

I would like the result to look like:

| catehgory_count | tweet_cathegory | tweet_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Personal Growth | AK |
| 15 | Health/Fitness | AL |

Comment: something like `select max(catehgory_count partition by tweet_state)`.... <<< Look for that

Comment: Wrap your query up as a subquery and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group.